# Solving non linear PDE using FiPy - Grid and diffusion term #Python

Tags: python, fipy

I am trying to use fipy to solve a non linear pde and i have a couple of questions regarding the usage.

1- can i set the grid1D object to start from a specific number rather than 0 ?

2- is it possible to use a coefficient variable with x as a diffusion coefficient ( if the phi is a function of t and x)? And how to do it?

Comment: Please, take a few minutes to read [how to ask useful questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and improve yours.

Answer (score 0):

1. All FiPy meshes can be displaced from \vec{0} by adding a vector of appropriate dimensionality, e.g.,

> ```
> >>> m1 = fp.Grid1D(nx=10, dx=.5) + [[5.]]
> >>> print m1.cellCenters
> [[ 5.25  5.75  6.25  6.75  7.25  7.75  8.25  8.75  9.25  9.75]]
>
> >>> m2 = fp.Grid2D(nx=3, ny=2, dx=.2, dy=.7) + [[2.], [8.]]
> >>> print m2.cellCenters
> [[ 2.1   2.3   2.5   2.1   2.3   2.5 ]
>  [ 8.35  8.35  8.35  9.05  9.05  9.05]]
> ```

2. `mesh.cellCenters` is a `CellVariable` and `mesh.faceCenters` is a `FaceVariable`, so just write your expression as you would any other:

> ```
> >>> x = mesh.cellCenters[0]
> >>> D = x**2 + 3.
> ```

Because FiPy interpolates diffusion coefficients defined at cell centers onto the face centers, thus you'll probably get more accurate results if you define your coefficient on face centers yourself

> ```
> >>> X = mesh.faceCenters[0]
> >>> D = X**2 + 3.
> ```

(see https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/FAQ.html#why-the-distinction-between-cellvariable-and-facevariable-coefficients)